# Jongo connect to remote MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, jongo

Is it possible to connect to a remote MongoDB when using Jongo ([jongo.org](http://jongo.org))?

I saw a piece of code where `MongoClientURI` was used like this:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://IP_ADDRESS:27017/DB_NAME");
```

I have the following code:

```
if(client != null) {
        db = client.getDatabase("StockApp");
        database = client.getDB("StockApp");
        jongo = new Jongo(database);

    }
```

In this example, `StockApp` is the name of my database. It will connect to my local database (127.0.0.1:27017/StockApp). When I try to change `StockApp` to `uri.getDatabase()` in both lines, I get the following exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

I can also see that it tries to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1).

When I change the uri to `new MongoClientURI("IP_ADDRESS")` or `new MongoClientURI("IP_ADDRESS:27017)` I get the error that the uri should start with `mongodb://`

Does anyone know if it is possible to connect to a remote MongoDB server using Jongo?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `Jongo` from a `MongoClient` like this:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("host", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("theDB");
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);
```

You can check the `MongoClient` constructor detail [here](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html)